# linux kernel: how packets hit taps on RX path

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, linux-kernel

I have an old server running Linux kernel `3.10.0`, for some reasons I can't upgrade this. So I'm trying to understand the receive path of packets:

(from https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/net/core/dev.c#3414)

```c
static int __netif_receive_skb_core(struct sk_buff *skb, bool pfmemalloc)
{
   ...
   another_round:
    ...

    list_for_each_entry_rcu(ptype, &ptype_all, list) {
      if (!ptype->dev || ptype->dev == skb->dev) {
        if (pt_prev)
            ret = deliver_skb(skb, pt_prev, orig_dev);
        pt_prev = ptype;
      }
    }
    ...

}
```

The function above also walks through `ptype_all` list and delivers a copy of the frame to each registered protocol sniffer. Does it include any `AF_PACKET` raw sockets as well?

The reason I'm asking is that I can't get my app receive packets: I opened a raw socket in `AF_PACKET` domain for `ARP` packets, bound it to the interface, I can see it exists via `/proc/net/packet`:

```
int sock;
struct sockaddr_ll sll;
const int val = 1;

sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ARP));
...
memset(&sll, 0, sizeof(sll));
sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
sll.sll_ifindex = ifindex;  /* ifindex is passed to this function */
sll.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ARP);

bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, sizeof(sll));
...

setsockopt(sock, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_AUXDATA, &val, sizeof(val));
...
```

Later on I read the socket queue and extract ancillary data:

```
...
struct msghdr msg;
struct iovec iov;
struct cmsghdr *cmsg;
char cmsg_buf[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(struct tpacket_auxdata))];
unsigned char buf[PKTLEN];
ssize_t nbytes;

msg.msg_name = &sll;
msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(sll);
msg.msg_iov = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
msg.msg_control = &cmsg_buf;
msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(cmsg_buf);
msg.msg_flags = 0;
...
nbytes = recvmsg(sockfd, &msg, 0);
...

/* walk through cmsg and read only PACKET_AUXDATA stored in struct tpacket_auxdata */
...
```

However it doesn't seem to hit that part of the code from above kernel code snippet, because I'm expecting to receive a frame with VLAN header *stripped off* but with VLAN metadata stored in `cmsg` in `tpacket_auxdata` structure (`tp_vlan_tci` field specifically), but `tp_vlan_tci` is set to zero.

Is there another type of sockets need to be created that will receive a copy if packets before the packets get handled by protocol specific handlers?

**UPDATE** It appears that changing the socket to `ETH_P_ALL` protocol helps, and I think it makes sense since `ptype_all` in the kernel points to sniffers registered with `ETH_P_ALL` "protocol" ?

Comment: Are you creating the socket with `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ARP))`? Maybe posting a [mre] of how you are trying to sniff these packets is a good idea.